# Calc 3 Question: Orthogonal Decomposition of Two Vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Let $u=\langle 1,2\rangle $ and $v=\langle −1,3\rangle$. Find the orthogonal decomposition of u in terms of v.

The answer should be given in this format: 
$$u=\langle , \rangle + \langle , \rangle $$

(The first pair is the parallel component and the second pair is the perpendicular component)

How do I find orthogonal decomposition of one vector in terms of another vector?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

$$u =\left(u-\frac{u.v}{v.v}v \right)+ \frac{u.v}{v.v}v$$

Check that $\left(u-\frac{u.v}{v.v}v \right)$ and $\frac{u.v}{v.v}v$ are orthogonal.

Comment: That’s a bit more than a hint. Aside from plugging in the numbers, that’s the entire solution.